# s3sync warning iconv will be deprecated

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, iconv

I've been happily using https://github.com/aproxacs/s3sync with Ruby 1.9.2.
Recently I upgraded to Ruby 1.9.3, and now I'm getting the following warning:

```
kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': iconv will be deprecated in the future, use String#encode instead.
```

I've had a go at editing the library, changing all references from Iconv.iconv to string.encode, e.g.

**old:**

```
result = Iconv.iconv("UTF-8", @nativeCharacterEncoding, string).join if @useUTF8InEscape
```

**new:**

```
result = string.encode(@nativeCharacterEncoding, :invalid => :replace, :undef => :replace, :replace => "-").join if @useUTF8InEscape
```

Unfortunately uploads no longer sync but but rather it uploads afresh each time.
Any idea on what I'm doing wrong or how to tackle this, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can see the problem this morning (marvellous what a good nights sleep will do).

I'd left the .join on the string encode.  I've now got s3sync working lovely with Ruby 1.9.3.  I published the gem if anyone else also has this problem:

[https://rubygems.org/gems/cprobert-s3sync](https://rubygems.org/gems/cprobert-s3sync)

The code for my fork is:

[https://github.com/cprobert/s3sync](https://github.com/cprobert/s3sync)